# Count the number of parents added in an Entity Framework (EF) transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have am using .NET Entity Framework 6 (EF6) to load parent/child data into a database.

A CVE is a 'parent' entity which has multiple children associated with it (for example "references", and "CVSS scores"). Once I have my context loaded with all the ojbects I want to save (CVEs and their associated children) I call "SaveChanges" and then want to know how many parent entities (CVEs) were inserted into the database.

Unfortunately the "SaveChanges" method returns the total number of objects added. I only want to know the number of CVE's (parent objects) added.

Here is my code;

```
internal static int LoadCVEs(IEnumerable<CVE> cves)
        {
            using (var context = new NVDEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach(var cve in cves)
                    {
                        var existingCVE = context.CVEs.Find(cve.CveID);

                        //Check if CVE already exists.
                        if (existingCVE != null)
                        {
                            //Check to see if this record was recently modified. If so, then replace the entire record with the latest one.
                                if (DateTimeOffset.Compare(cve.ModifiedDate.Value, existingCVE.ModifiedDate.Value) > 0)
                                {
                                    //CVE has been recently modified. Replace the outdated record.
                                    context.CVEs.Remove(existingCVE);
                                    context.CVEs.Add(cve);
                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //CVE is new. Insert it.
                            context.CVEs.Add(cve);
                        }
                    }

                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
    }
```

Among other things, I have tried the following;

```
context.CVEs.Where(c => context.Entry(c).State == EntityState.Added).Count()
```

But that returns the following error;

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry`1[NVDImport.Models.CVE]
>   EntryCVE' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

How do I get the total count of CVEs (parent objects) that were added?

Comment: Do you need the count within the same method? Couldn't you just keep track of how many you add within that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

In your DbContext inheriting class, you want to override your SaveChanges() method:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {

        int cveCount = ChangeTracker.Entries<CVE>().Where(argEntry => argEntry.State == EntityState.Added).Count();

        base.SaveChanges();

        return cveCount;
    }
```

Comment: I actually just figured this out on my own, but you confirmed this was a proper solution. thanks +1 and tick.